Matching only unique participants
I am having trouble matching my historical cohort to a study cohort in R studio.
Objective: Get a match to every patient in my study cohort using the historical cohort.
I want each patient in the historical cohort to be matched only once maximum to a study patient.
However, a patient can be present in the historical dataset several times, because my dataset of historical patients includes a row for every visit of every patient.
I want every visit of the same patient to be a possible match but would like to match each historical patient just once.
If a historical patient is matched, I do not want another visit of the same patient to be matched.
Details of the historical dataset:

I have a variable with a number for the unique visit.
I have a variable with the patient ID.

So far, I have not succeeded.  Could you help me with the code?
I have tried this code below, but end up with one historical patient being matched several times, on different time points.
My code:
# Load dplyr and MatchIt
library(dplyr)
library(MatchIt)

# Example data for study_cohort dataset
study_cohort <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:20,
  Age = sample(25:65, 20, replace = TRUE),
  Meds = sample(1:5, 20, replace = TRUE)
)

# Example data for historical_cohort dataset
historical_cohort <- data.frame(
  VisitID = 1:80,
  ID = sprintf("%05d", 101:120)[sample(1:20, 80, replace = TRUE)],  # Willekeurige selectie van historische IDs
  Age = sample(25:65, 80, replace = TRUE),
  Meds = sample(1:5, 80, replace = TRUE)
)

# Convert to have the same in both datasets 
study_cohort$ID <- as.character(study_cohort$ID)

# Combine the two datasets 
study_cohort$group <- 1 # study 
historical_cohort$group <- 0 # historical

combined_data <- bind_rows(study_cohort, historical_cohort)

# Match
match_formula <- as.formula("group ~ Age + Meds")

matched <- matchit(match_formula, data = combined_data, method = "nearest", ratio = 1, replace =  FALSE)

matched_data <- match.data(matched)

# Split dataset
matched_study <- matched_data %>%
  filter(group == "1") # study

matched_historical <- matched_data %>%
  filter(group == "0") # historical

# Inspect data of matched_historical
View(matched_historical)
# When I inspect this data I see that several patients are used multiple times, but at different visits, which is not my intention

Furthermore, I have tried to only select one visit per patient, but then only the first visit of each historical patient can be a potential match, even though I want all visits to be potential matches.

in your example Meds and Age are time-varying by visit in the historical cohort. Is this just an artifact of your example data generation process, or is this true, such that a study cohort id should be matched to the visit with the closest age match and closest meds match?

Thank you langtang,
It is true that the historical patients use different types of medication on the different visit dates. Therefore a historical patient could be a match to e.g. study patient 1 on one visit date but not on another visit date.

Did you try the unit.id argument, which is specifically designed for this purpose?

Thank you! I was not aware of this argument, but this is exactly what I needed :)
